# Site to site VPN established with Azure, but no communication either way

Tags: windows, vpn, azure

I have setup a VPN connection between my Azure tenant and on-premises Windows Server 2019 machine (RRAS server), however I am not seeing any traffic.

I can RDP and ping the public IP address of the Azure VM from Windows Server.

My setup is as follows:

**my azure vm** has private ip of 10.1.0.4 and public ip of 20.180.x.x.

**my on-premises windows server:**

ethernet adaptor

ip add : 10.0.2.15

netmask 255.255.255.0

gateway 10.0.2.2

ppp adaptor

ip add 169.254.0.x

netmask 255.255.0.0

**my azure vm network details:**

ip add v6 10.1.0.4

netmask 255.255.255.192

gateway 10.1.0.1

**from windows server:**

ping 10.1.0.4 fails as request timed out

**from azure vm:**

ping 10.0.2.15 fails as request timed out

Comment: 10.1.0.4 is private ip address for azure vm

Comment: As first try to telnet the rdp prot from your onprem vpn gateway into the azure vm. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that stands out to me is the line "ip add v6 10.1.0.4", which suggests an IPv6 address, but contains an IPv4 address. Double check to make sure your Azure VM's NIC has its IPv*4* address configured as 10.1.0.4.